# Java How to avoid String Index out of Bounds

Tags: java, string, stringindexoutofbounds

I have the following task to do:

> Return true if the string "cat" and "dog" appear the same number of
>   times in the given string.
>
> catDog("catdog") → true catDog("catcat") → false
>   catDog("1cat1cadodog") → true

my code:

```
public boolean catDog(String str) {
int catC = 0;
int dogC = 0;
if(str.length() < 3) return true;
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
   if(str.charAt(i) == 'd' && str.charAt(i+1) == 'o' && str.charAt(i+2)  == 'g'){
     dogC++;
   }else if(str.charAt(i) == 'c' && str.charAt(i+1) == 'a' && 
                                       str.charAt(i+2) == 't'){
    catC++;
  }
}

if(catC == dogC) return true;
return false;
}
```

But for `catDog("catxdogxdogxca")` → `false` I'm getting a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I know it's caused by the if clause when it tries to check if the `charAt(i+2)` equals t. How can I avoid this? 
Thanks in regards :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){ // you problem lies here
   if(str.charAt(i) == 'd' && str.charAt(i+1) == 'o' && str.charAt(i+2)  == 'g')
```

You are using the `i < str.length()` as the *loop termination condition* but you are using `str.charAt(i+1)` and `str.charAt(i+2)`

Since you need to access **`i+2`**, then you should limit the range by **`i < str.length() - 2`** instead.

```
for(int i = 0, len = str.length - 2; i < len; i++) 
// avoid calculating each time by using len in initialising phase;
```

Comment: That was way to simple for me xD 
I solved it myself with adding str.length() >= i+3 && to both if clauses but your method is way better.

Comment: @user8953265 I updated the solution further, if it solved your problem. Please mark it as the answer for later reference. ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with logic, the conditional statements are trying to access character which is out of string size.

Input: **catxdogxdogxca** have **ca** at the end that's why **else** block is executed and which tries to get character present at i+3 which does not exist in the input. That's why you are seeing **java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**.